# Java - concurrency/blocking queue unit testing strategies

Tags: java, testing, concurrency

I have a program that operates pulls work items off a blocking queue and works on them concurrently. I realise this is a VERY loose description, but can anyone suggest a unit testing strategy/ideas on what to test?

Comment: What are you trying to test, the validity of the BlockingQueue or concurrent processing on the returned value?

Comment: I have tested the validity of the actual work the blocking queue handler works on, but I want to test the code surrounding it's operation.

Comment: Testing for concurrency is tricky: you can have a badly multi-threaded program that will pass all tests flawlessly on some platforms (e.g. a single core CPU), but fail on others.  Even if your tests are successful on a multicore CPU, the thread scheduling varies for different OS's and they could fail elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Use the worker queue mechanisms in java.util.concurrent and rely on them to test their code. Then just test your worker to make sure it does the correct thing. If it is independent of other threads that should be enough. Otherwise you will likely need to come up with an integration testing strategy on hardware/os/jvm configurations that match your production environment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to design it to be tested.

So specific suggestions:

- Make sure that you can place test classes or mocks into the queue
- Code some early mocks to take longer and be sure that they aren't the first ones completed (demonstrates concurrency)
- Make sure your results collection is equal in size to all your tests.
- Make sure your results aren't complete until the time allocated for the longest test.

hmm, it all stems from being able to inject mocks/test classes into the queue.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of depends on what sort of processing your classes do, to the items that are pulled off.  For example, suppose they write the items to a database.  You might want tests like these.

- A single thread can pull an item from the queue and save it to the database.
- Two threads can pull items from the queue concurrently, and the data is saved if the first thread tries to save first.
- Two threads can pull items from the queue concurrently, and the data is saved if the second thread tries to save first.
- Fifty threads (or whatever limit is appropriate for your program) can pull items from the queue concurrently, and save the data correctly.

If you're using one of the JDK blocking queue implementations, or an implementation from a third party, then please make sure that you don't try to test the behaviour of the blocking queue class itself.  Of course, if you've written your own, then you've got a whole lot more tests that you need to write.

Hope this helps.